# file_get_contents | escaping doesnt show the page

Tags: escaping

I have below code.`echo $FileContents;`shows the page which comes the php variable correctly, but the escape function which is   `<?php esc_html( $FileContents ); ?>`didnt show anything.

How can I escape it correctly and show the page?

```
<?php global $redux_demo; ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ulockd-mrgn1210">
        <?php $FileContents = file_get_contents($redux_demo['text-location-service-details']); ?>
        <?php echo $FileContents; ?>
        <?php esc_html( $FileContents ); ?>
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html) doesn't echo/display the return value (escaped string), so you need to call `echo` manually:

```php
echo esc_html( $FileContents );
```

### Update

If you actually want to filter the list of allowed HTML tags in the variable's value, then you can use the WordPress' KSES functions like [`wp_kses_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/) and [`wp_kses_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_data/):

```php
echo wp_kses_post( $FileContents );
echo wp_kses_data( $FileContents ); // allows basic HTML by default
```

Comment: when I use it like you said, it print html as text like source code, not visual

Comment: That's how `esc_html()` works. Your question was also about showing the escaped value, right? But check the revised answer and see if it helps.